# Permissions issue with netatalk

Tags: server, permissions, sharing

I set up an Ubuntu 12.04 server recently for my business, and we installed netatalk so we could share company files to our Mac computers. Here is the line we used in our AppleVolumes.default file:

```
/media/files/business  "Business"  allow:@business  perm:0770  umask:0007
```

Also, our primary group for all users is "business".

So here's the issue. When we move a bunch of files and folders over, the correct permissions are set (770), but for some reason, for certain filetypes, the will only open for the owner.

A text document will work for anyone, where as an .mp4 file only works for it's owner, even though their permissions are identical:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 user1 business 205328400 Jan  6 15:00 Video.mp4
-rwxrwx--- 1 user1 business 665       Feb 21 09:14 Business.rtf
```

NOTES:

- Server is Ubuntu 12.04. Everything is up to date.
- We are exclusively Mac. All of our Macs run OS X Mavericks.
- We have a Drobo that hosts our files currently (also using AFP), and it works fine when we use it. So we know it's not our computers.
- The AFP shares are on the Ubuntu server all being shared from a local partition being mounted by fstab on boot.

UPDATE (3/14/14):

I got some help from sarnold on the #ubuntu-server channel, we tried removing extended attributes from all these files by mounting the partition without the extended attributes. After testing, it didn't help any.

UPDATE (3/17/14):

I tested if maybe it was a file size issue, but big text files over 200MB were fine, and really small .zip files under 1MB didn't work for non-owners. I also gave full permissions (777) to a zip file, and that didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out that I was running Netatalk 2. I updated to Netatalk 3.1 and all of my issues are now resolved.